# SQL help on previous value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I have table like this

[image]

I need a result with last column Parent item

[image]

Parent Item column should get value of Product No if Lvl =1 then populate product no value where Lvl=0 like wise if Lvl=2 then populate product no value where lvl=1. I tried with below query but not getting correct output

```sql
select ABC, lvl as Lvl,Product_no,
   case        
              when lvl = 1  then lag(ref) over(order by ABC) 
               when lvl = 2 then lag(ref) over(order by ABC ) end   as
```

[Parent Item]

One more example
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1P3TZ.png)

Comment: Use a Self Join to the table.

Comment: can you please help me with the query

Comment: @MaheshPatil . . . There is not enough information in the table to solve the problem.  You seem to be relying on the ordering of rows, but SQL tables represent unordered (multi)sets.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with the query:

```
Select 
T1.ABC, 
T1.Lvl, 
T1.ProductNo,
(Select ProductNo From TableName where Lvl = T1.Lvl - 1) as parantProduct
From TableName T1
```

This does take into account if there can be multiple parent items.

You need more info if you should be able to get the last row correct (ProductNo L97****)

Comment: last row should populate value where lvl=1

Comment: I am getting error Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: yes but your example, there is two rows with lvl = 1. What rule do you want to implement to choose between those?

Comment: If you have one ID column that said 1,2,3,4,5 etc, You could select highest of those that is less than the row itself. But I don't see any such column now.

Comment: i have more then 1 and 2s in lvl column

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be defining the parents based on the ordering of the rows.  However, SQL (in general) does not have an ordering for the rows.  If I assume that you have another column with this information, then you could use `APPLY` to get the previous row at a higher level:

```
select t.*, tp.*
from t outer apply
     (select top (1) tp.*
      from t tp
      where tp.abc = t.abc and
            tp.lvl = t.lvl - 1 and
            tp.<ordering column> < t.<ordering column>
      order by tp.<ordering column> desc
     ) tp;
```

Comment: 1JQ20AV 0 1JQ20AV NULL
1JQ20AV 1 838898-009 2B3W4AV
1JQ20AV 2 L94563-001 M43620-001
1JQ20AV 1 937923-011 2B3W4AV
1JQ20AV 2 611894-007 M43620-001
1JQ20AV 2 488507-003 M43620-001

Comment: M43620-001 is repeating for all other  ABCs

Comment: I think i have to use ROW_NUMBER() OVER can you help me with this

Comment: I edited my post which has one more example and i need result like that

Comment: @MaheshPatil . . . It all depends on the column you use for ordering and that is not yet part of your question.

Comment: There is no order in the above one more example link lvl  is in 0 1 1 2 1 2

Comment: @MaheshPatil . . . You are missing my point.  Your question cannot be answered using. a table that has no column that specifies the ordering.  Tables are **unordered**.  Your logic seems to imply an ordering.

Comment: Where ever 2 it’s should reflect previous 1 product no in parent item that is lvl 1